# How to implement remember me programatically in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, remember-me

I have implemented a login function programmatically.

This code is following:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->getRequest(),$token);
$this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch('security.interactive_login', $event);
```

After this, how do I implement remember me ?

（I know how to use form, but I want to implement remember me programmatically. ）

please help...

Comment: You might check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549) for a general picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use [RememberMeToken](https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Core/Authentication/Token/RememberMeToken.php)

```
$key = $this->getParameter('secret'); // your security key from parameters.yml

$token = new RememberMeToken($user, 'main', $key); 
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a facebook login.
This log me in, but does not create a cookie.

`$token = new RememberMeToken($user, 'default', $this->getParameter('secret'));
            $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);`

In my security.yml:

`security:
  firewalls:
    default:
       remember_me:
       key:                '%secret%'
       lifetime:           31536000
       always_remember_me: true`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.you should use `RememberMeToken` instead of `UsernamePasswordToken`.

The class parameters are  very similar to UsernamePasswordToken  so I don't go into details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cookie with an unique ID. Then store this cookie in a database and check this database whenever a new visitor visits the site. In case you have your users stored in a database it would be best to make an extra column to store this information. Have a look at FOSUserBundle by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same method as forgottenbas suggested, but got an error. I had to use $this->container (Symfony2):

```
$key = $this->container->getParameter('secret');

$token = new RememberMeToken($user, 'user_area', $key); 
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

$user is an instance of my User class and 'user_area' is the name of my firewall.